# WPF : How to pin exe to top and center of the screen? also give effect

Tags: wpf

How to create professional good looking WPF application with Very GOod GUI?

Comment: Youtube is of another programmer, reinventing the GUI wheel. Use the facilities built into the operating system to allow for a clean and consistent experience - do not reinvent them.

Comment: I'm less worried about the lack of answer acceptance than I am about the question itself. Yes, it's unclear and missing details. But also, please don't do this nonsense. I can guarantee that no one wants your software hanging open on top of their screen *at all times*. Follow standard Windows conventions, and your users will thank you.

Comment: Sorry for asking such question but I am new to WPF and just want to know how to do things like this..Please give me some Guidance in WPF either.

Comment: @Cody Gray "no one wants your software hanging open on top of their screen at all times" is your opinion and not fact. Have a look at Jing. It does exactly that and is within Top100 products of PCWorld 2008.

Comment: @NVM: I've never heard of it, and I'm far from impressed looking at the website. There are much better screenshot programs that don't clutter up your desktop and are accessible using the keyboard, rather than clicking on non-descript icons. Being in the top 100 products published by some magazine doesn't prove real-world usage. It just proves that it fit the criteria used by some editor.

Comment: I exacly want to hang application like Jing application on the center screen.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/).  They are a .NET training company with tons of material on WPF.